# Update to Ubuntu 15.10 freeze on startup (Ubuntu logo)

Tags: kernel, 15.10

Upgrade my laptop to Ubuntu 15.10. After I restart it freeze in Ubuntu logo.

I found out that I'm having problem with the new kernel (Linux 4.2.0-16-generic). If I use the 2nd version (Linux 3.19-generic) it boots properly.

When I tried removing Linux 4.2.0-16-generic and run *sudo update-grub* it always detects Linux 4.2.0-16-generic.

How would I make *Linux 3.19-generic* the default upon boot up? And/Or permanently remove Linux 4.2.0-16-generic?

Comment: I have a similar problem with 4.2.0 and later kernels, so I have been using 3.19.  However, I recently tried 4.1.12 and all is well thus far. You might try it if you want a more current kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Install Synaptic and remove 4.2 kernel image and headers.

You removed only meta-packages.

Comment: I already did this. I search and remove every 4.2 Kernel in Synaptic. When I restart, 4.2 still shows in grub. What did I missed?

Comment: You did not search well ;-) Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` to your question.

Comment: If you like, you can vote to delete this correct answer.)))

Comment: @Max: Answer is correct: please edit your answer and provide the output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`...

Comment: @Fabby `update-grub` is run automatically when you remove kernels.

Comment: Comment updated!  **:P**

Comment: @Pilot6 Sorry for my late reply. Yesterday, I tried searching "everything" and deleting all 4.2 Kernel in Synaptic and it works! Thanks Pilot6

Comment: So you can accept the answer by clicking the check sign at the left.